# SQL - Get Records within Date Range using 2 tables (Date Range/Hours given)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have 2 tables:

**Table 1:**

```
Name, StartDate, EndDate
```

Ex:

```
Timmy, 9/12/17 08:00:00, 9/13/17 00:00:00   
Timmy, 9/13/17 05:00:00, 9/13/17 07:00:00
```

Table 2:

```
Name, StartHour, Data...
```

Ex:

```
Timmy, 9/13/17 06:00:00, Data1...   
Timmy, 9/13/17 04:00:00, Data2...   
Timmy, 9/13/17 07:00:00, Data3...  
Timmy, 9/12/17 14:00:00, Data4...
```

So, I need to get every record in Table 2 where that start hour is NOT inside of a date range in Table 1. This needs to be done for every name (so there can be multiple matching names in T1/T2 (see T2's data columns are different). It should be inclusive on the left side, exclusive on the right side.

So for this query, I want to see

```
Timmy, 9/13/17 04:00:00, Data2...  
Timmy, 9/13/17 07:00:00, Data3... (Inclusive on end date)
```

I don't mind if its joined; I can just remove extra columns. I don't want to see duplicates though. I also keep hitting problems where I'll check if NOT (StartHour  >= StartDate AND StartHour < EndDate). So each row/startHour in Table 2 needs to be checked against every row with a matching name in Table 1. I can't deal with that; I think it needs a subquery, but I don't know.

Checking if it is inside the ranges, but then negate because I don't want them if they are inside the range (inclusive,exclusive).

Comment: But the two records you showed in the output actually fall between the start and enddate of Table1. Do you want to remove these two records or keep them?

Comment: @Vashi Sorry, maybe I messed up. The first record is after the range in Table 1, record one. Then it is before the range in Table 1, record two.  The second returned record is after T1 record 1, and after T1 record 2 (the End Date is not inclusive. So T1 R2 ends at 07:00, Returned result 2 starts at 07:00 (it should be non inclusive for end date, so that's ok).

Answer (score 0):

My solution attempt was:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 
ON T1.Name = T2.Name  
AND NOT (T2.StartHour >= T1.StartDate AND T2.StartHour < T2.EndDate)
```

Then just grab where there are no nulls.

That conditional can evaluate to true where in the row from T2 hits false for T1 row 1, but T1 row 2, 3, 4,... it is actually true, so I get 4 results back or whatever. Or it just doesn't evaluate it correctly because It doesn't look at all rows in T1.

Answer (score 0):

For every entry of table2 matching with table1 you can calculate a count of how many times the condition is violated and if it is violated even once, you don't want that in the output. This is done by using a `SUM(CASE WHEN..)` in the below query.

```
SELECT T2.NAME, T2.STARTHOUR, T2.DATA
FROM
TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN
TABLE2 T2
ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
GROUP BY T2.NAME, T2.STARTHOUR, T2.DATA
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN T2.STARTHOUR >= T1.STARTDATE AND T2.STARTHOUR < T1.STARTDATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

As per exclusion and inclusion rules, you can see that the rule is not violated if table2's `starthour` is same as table1's `enddate`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.* 
FROM Table2 T2
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 T1 WHERE 
        T1.Name = T2.Name
        AND T2.StartHour > T1.StartDate 
        AND T2.StartHour < T1.EndDate )
```